# Looking for a general name or term for this particular database table design

Tags: terminology, database-schema

I've run into a particular SQL table design and I'm trying to see if there's a common name people use to describe it. The table has a definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [ATTRIBUTES] (
  [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [FIELD_1] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_1] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_2] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_2] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_3] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_3] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_4] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_4] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_5] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_5] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_6] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_6] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_7] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_7] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_8] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_8] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_9] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_9] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [FIELD_10] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [VALUE_10] [varchar](30) NULL
)
```

The idea is to allow a variable number of attributes to be defined (up to a max of 10 in this case), without using a more normalized design.

I'm not looking for the pros/cons of this approach, but does anyone know of a common name or term used to describe this type of database table design?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would call it a (particularly nasty) form of a key-value store.

Comment: Thanks driis! As I read your answer it seemed like a very good term to use. The only addition I might add would be to call it a *limited* key-value store, or use some similar adjective to indicate the limitation on the number of pairs.

Comment: This is anything but a key value store.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically referred to as the Attribute Columns pattern when people aren't busy calling it a pile of crap.